# Downloading file with AJAX. From a SD card.

Tags: javascript, html, c, ajax, http

I using  Atmel SAM4E-EK micro controller as a server where a webpage is created and I'm sending data over HTTP protocol. But I'm stuck in the download function where I'm trying to download a file from my sd_card the file will no bigger than 512MB.

```
static int cgi_Download_File(const char *name, char *recv_buf, size_t recv_len)
{

    UNUSED(recv_buf);
    UNUSED(recv_len);
    UNUSED(name);
    uint32_t length = 0;
    int i;
st = f_open(&file_logging, "Logging_File.csv",FA_OPEN_EXISTING | FA_READ);


    for (i=0; i<; i++)
    {
        st = f_read(&file_logging, Buff_logging ,128 , &br);

        sprintf((char *)tx_buf,
        "{ \"Download_test\":\"%s\"}",
            Buff_logging);

        http_sendOk(HTTP_CONTENT_JSON);
        http_write((char const *)tx_buf, strlen((char *)tx_buf));

    }


}
```

The above code is where I'm reading the file form the sd card and trying to send it over HTTP protocol to the client. I cannot read more then 12kb at one time because I'm occupation all my memory.  So I'm dividing the file into packages, so basically Buff_logging is my package which is 512 bytes.

```
$(function() {
          $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "get_Download_File",
              type: "GET",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(result) {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(result);
                var $a = $('Download_test', {
                  'href': url,
                  'download': 'document.csv',
                  'text': "click"
                }).hide().appendTo("body")[0].click();
                setTimeout(function() {
                  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }, 10000);
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

This is form the client side where I'm using AJAX for the file downloading. Basically what I'm trying to achive here is get the packages one by one in sequential order and restore them in the clients disk as a csv file. The ajax function work only for the first 512 bytes then I do't receive any packets any more.

I want to mention that I've no experience with Java HTML or AJAX I'm more into low level programming , but I'll appreciate the help to tell me if my code has a potential or this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Can you link the documentation for http_sendOk and http_write/

Comment: What do you mean exactly??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in your loop:

```
for (i=0; i<; i++)
{
    ...

    http_sendOk(HTTP_CONTENT_JSON);
    http_write((char const *)tx_buf, strlen((char *)tx_buf));

}
```

`http_sendOk` will be sending a content-type header with every read, but the HTTP headers must come before the response body and only occur once.

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but moving the `http_sendOk` outside of the loop (initialize once) and leaving the `http_write` within the loop (write many packets of data) might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you ssube! But that didn't help I think My mistake is the client because again I'm getting only the first package.

Comment: It sounds like `http_sendOk` wasn't your only problem. Something is closing the request after the first `http_write`, rather than allowing the HTTP request to continue as you stream data into it. I can't find the docs for `http_write`, so I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
void http_write(const char *buf, u32_t len)enter code here
{
    g_hs->file = buf;
g_hs->left = len;

http_send_data(g_pcb, g_hs);

/*
 * Tell TCP that we wish be to informed of buf that has been
 * successfully sent by a call to the http_sent() callback.
 */
tcp_sent(g_pcb, http_sent);
}
```

That is the function directly form the library.....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for the moment I have achieved to transfer packets to he client, but that did not clear out my problem. I can send maximum 20 packet 2560 bytes in the maximum that I can store in my server. 
Is it possible to achieve some kind of stream 
**First** read 128b form SD_card file 
**Second** send to Client over HTTP
**Third** Client gets the package
**Fourth** Packet is downloading (The downloading process must stop when all the packets are send)

I have achieved the first 3 steps, so please can someone help how I can achive that stream effect.